# setTimeout in IE 11 is not working properly

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am using the setTimeout function to set the focus on a button element of a bootstrap modal. The following is the small piece of code which I wrote:

```
let element = this.el.nativeElement;
setTimeout(() => element.focus(), 200);
```

This works correctly on Firefox and Chrome. But on IE 11, I get the focus on the button for a blink of a second and it looses focus.

Do I have to do anything different in the case of IE 11 here? Am I doing something wrong?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Cheers.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with IE's `setTimeout` implementation, but ES6 arrow functions are not supported.

Comment: got it! Thanks. :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

IE11 doesn't support arrow functions. You will need to pass a function reference instead:

```
setTimeout(function (){ element.focus(); }, 200);
```

Comment: Got it thank you :) I found this right now https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Great works for IE,